# return после завершения анимации

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

```
class MyApp():
       def build(self):
           def anim_compleate(animtion, widget):
               after_button = Button(text='123') # просто набросок кнопки
               return after_button   
            
           wimg = FloatLayout()
           wimg.add_widget(Image(source="1234.png"))
           Window.clearcolor = (100, 100, 100, 1)
           anim = Animation(opacity=0.0, duration=2)
           anim.start(wimg)
           anim.bind(on_complete=anim_compleate)
            
           return wimg
```

Цель данного кода, по завершению анимации обратится к функции `anim_complete` и создать кнопку, но почему-то функция `anim_complete` просто "не видит" `return`. Пожалуйста подскажите что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: совсем непонятно, откуда и куда нужно вернуться. В коде два ретурна, о каком речь? Что конкретно означает "не видит"?

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. Опишите человеческим языком: какой результат работы вы ожидали от кода и какой наблюдается в реальности.

Comment: я же написал друзья,что мне нужно создать кнопку после завершения анимации,что тут непонятного?

Comment: А может сразу задать при создании анимации `anim = Animation(opacity=0.0, duration=2, on_complete=anim_compleate)`?

Comment: давайте на минуту оставим данный код и я сформирую опрос по другому,как я могу после завершения анимации создать кнопку?